# Copy certain rows from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to insert *certain* values from an existing database into another. I know i can use the following, but i also want to insert other values (that don't exist in any database but are (for example) post values)

```
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO log (
        f1,
        f2,
        f3,
        f4
    )
    SELECT 
        a1,
        a2,
        a3,  
        a4  
    FROM
        db
    WHERE
        a1 = '1'
") or die(mysql_error());
```

This only copies full database records, where i want to add other values. Something like

```
INSERT
    $_POST['field1'], 
    a1, 
    a2, 
    $_POST['field2']
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just constants in SELECT, example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (f1, f2, f3, f4)
    SELECT ".mysql_escape_string($_POST['field1']).",
           a1, a2,
           ".mysql_escape_string($_POST['field2'])."
    FROM
        db
    WHERE
        a1 = '1' ") or die(mysql_error());
```